# Issue unwrapping string from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to get a value from NSUserDefaults and I am trying to set a variable to be this. The problem is that I am unsure about how I unwrap it?

This is my code:

```
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt")
    currentBudgetCalculation = defaults?.stringForKey("currentBudgetWidget")!
```

At the moment I just get an error on the second line that states:

```
Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

If I try to use the suggested solution, it just adds a `!` to the end of the line, but this obviously doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
currentBudgetCalculation = defaults!.stringForKey("currentBudgetWidget")!
```

Comment: Ah. Your answer is almost correct, but it's `currentBudgetCalculation = defaults!.stringForKey("currentBudgetWidget")!`

Comment: I had to wait for the time limit to expire, but I've done it now. Thanks!

Comment: Note that using forced unwrapping will cause the app to crash if `defaults` is nil, or if there's no value for `currentBudgetWidget`, or if it's not castable to a string

Answer (score 2):

Note that using the forced unwrapping operator `!` is not recommended because it generates a runtime error if the optional is `nil`.

A better approach is to use optional binding, which makes your code safer and less prone to exceptions, especially when you are not sure whether an optional variable actually contains a non nil value:

```
var defaults: NSUserDefaults? = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt")

if let defaults = defaults {
    if let currentBudgetCalculation: String = defaults.stringForKey("currentBudgetWidget") {
        // Here you are 100% sure currentBudgetCalculation contains a non nil value
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, I always avoid the forced unwrapping operator `!`, unless it's me assigning a non-nil value from my own code - using it on something that's returned by a function or method can be source of headaches trying to figure out why the app crashes for unknown reasons. This is mentioned in the official documentation [If Statements and Forced Unwrapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_501) with a note:

> Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.